# Generalization of the concept of real valued function of class $k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\text{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ a real valued function where I is an interval contained in $\mathbb{R}$. We say that f is of class 0 if $f$ is a continuous function on I. We say that $f$ is of class 1 (and is denoted by $C^1$) if f is a differentiable function whose derivative is continuous... We say that $f$ is of class n if $f$ is n times differentiable and the n-th derivative function is continuous... And $f$ is of class infinity (and is denoted by $C^{\infty}$) if $f$ is in $C^n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Intuitively, if f is of class k and g is of class k+1, the graph of g seems to be smoother than the one of $f$... Is there any coherent definition of a function of class $r$ where $r$ is a non-negative real number?

Comment: Try [Hölder spaces][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holder_space

Comment: Note that Holder with exponent $1$ is called Lipschitz, and is still not as smooth as a $C^1$ function. So there is a bit of wiggle room, and more precise classifications are used, for instance, in PDE.